# Can I use another prefix instead of `ng` with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm newbie to angularjs. When I read the docs, I found it uses `ng` as prefix of attributes:

```
<body ng:controller="PhoneListCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng:repeat="phone in phones">
      {{phone.name}}
      <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

I want to know if I can modify it as another word, such as `x`? Since I think `x` is much easier to type than `ng`.

Comment: You could fork it, and 'ng' with 'x' replace, then do `git rebase` ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since **v1.0.0rc1**, these are all equivalent:

```
<div ng-show="isVisible">Using ng-show</div>
<div ng:show="isVisible">Using ng:show</div>
<div data-ng-show="isVisible">Using data-ng-show</div>
<div x-ng-show="isVisible">Using x-ng-show</div>
<div class="ng-show:isVisible">Using class="ng-show:isVisible"</div>
```

Here's working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/Fgf3Q/

However, the main reason behind this was allowing valid html. So, you ca use `x-*` prefix for your custom directives, but not for Angular ones.

Check out [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$compileProvider#directive) for more info.

Comment: Although this is not exactly what I want -- I hope to use `x-show` instead of `ng-show`, but I learn more about angularjs, thank you!

Comment: I kind of expected x:* to work (after setting xmlns:x="http://angularjs.org"), but it doesn't...

Comment: Does `data-x-mydirective` work? (`x-mydirective` is not valid HTML5?)

Comment: `data-mydirective` works and is valid html5, why would you need `data-x-mydirective` ?

Comment: very helpful, thanks! this also addresses some of the concerns w/ Angular not using valid HTML (using data- instead of ng- directives)

Comment: That said, I think somebody should create a better html validator that can understand Angular stuff. Using `data-*` makes the templates awfull and only causes to "skip" these attributes as valid. Would be better to actually validate even the Angular attributes and produce errors like "you misspelled ng-rrepeat". It's not simple, but somebody should try it ;-)

Comment: Multiple personalities much? I like the class and data syntaxes but the others just add confusion :-(