# AngularJS tags attributes

Tags: html, angularjs

I am learning about AngularJS and see it adds some of its own attributes that nor start with data neither are standard html tags attributes, like this:

```
<html ng-app>
```

or this:

```
<body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
```

Where from do these ng-* attributes come and is that a valid HTML? Where can I read more about this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Strictly speaking these extra attributes are not defined in the HTML specifications thus, are not valid HTML. You could say that AngularJS provides and parses a superset of the HTML specification.

However, as of v1.0.0rc1, you could use data-* attributes, for example `<html data-ng-app>` which, I believe, are valid HTML5. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746916/can-i-use-another-prefix-instead-of-ng-with-angularjs?rq=1).

There is a guide to the [AngularJS Compiler](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) that contains some more information on the process. In short; the AngularJS compiler reads your HTML page, using these attributes to guide it as it edits and updates your page, after loading, via javascript and the HTML DOM.

Comment: Just to leave this clear, **yes**, `data-X` is HTML5-compliant, since the `data-` prefix is for custom attributes.

Answer (score 27):

From the docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-ng-controller="Ctrl1">
      These are all valid directive declarations:<br/>
      <input ng-model='name'> <hr/>
      <span ng:bind="name"></span> <br/>
      <span ng_bind="name"></span> <br/>
      <span ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>          
      <span x-ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
      <span data-ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I like the `data-*whatever*` declaration the best as it's HTML5 compliant.

So for any of my Angular declaration (e.g. `ng-controller`, `ng-app`, `ng-repeat` etc) or custom directives I'll always prefix them with `data-`.

Answer (score 8):

> Where from do these ng-* attributes come

From main [ng module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng). [Source code](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.1/angular-1.0.1.js).

> is that a valid HTML?

No. But attribute-style directives can be prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant. See [direcives documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to ignore undefined attribute names. If you are using Eclipse, you can set this by going to project `properties>>validation>>html syntax>>attributes>>ignore undefined attribute names`.