# AngularJS app not passing official W3C HTML5 validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, w3c-validation

I have a project where I'm using AngularJS, but one of the requirements is that my app must pass official HTML5 and CSS3 validation.

Why are apps built with AngularJS not passing official W3C HTML5 validation? I really like AngularJS, so what should I do? Do I really have to build it from scratch or is there any reasonable article/blog which address this issue so I can explain it to my professor?

Comment: "*Why are apps built with AngularJS not passing official W3C HTML5 validation*"  Who says they aren't? Please add a [mcve] of your AngularJS code that fails W3C validation, including the error message your code generates.

Comment: I would first question the requirement

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to some other Stackoverflow QA you can pre-fix your angularjs attributes with the `data-` attribute.

So `ng-app` would become `data-ng-app`. This would mean that your markup is valid html5 and still work with angularjs.

See these questions for reference.

[AngularJS tags attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107504/angularjs-tags-attributes)

[Can I use another prefix instead of `ng` with angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746916/can-i-use-another-prefix-instead-of-ng-with-angularjs?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

It is very late to this answer, but I wrote a basic tool called [angular-html5](https://github.com/pgilad/angular-html5) which will convert directives to `data-directives` automatically. There are also [grunt](https://github.com/pgilad/grunt-angular-htmlify) and [gulp](https://github.com/pgilad/gulp-angular-htmlify) plugins to be used in build steps.

That way you can still write:

```
<div ng-if="whatever"></div>
```

And it will turn into:

```
<div data-ng-if="whatever"></div>
```

Just add it to your workflow, and you can use it similarly to using [ng-min](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) for minification.

See [Angular Directives Normalization Rules](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for further information.