# ng-click as a class in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I'm trying to work out why this doesn't work:

```
<a class="ng-click: loadSomeDatas();">Click here to load some datas</a>
```

But this does:

```
<a ng-click="loadSomeDatas()">Click here to load some datas</a>
```

**Why are you using classes?**

Well ng-* attributes don't play nice on some of the clients I have to support, thus rather than shimming them I'd rather just use good ol' safe classes.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a documentation error.  According to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js), it can only be used as an attribute.  The link function does not use `restrict` so the default is "attribute only".

Comment: It's a shame that I have to use the attribute. I might have to consider attaching the event in another way.

Comment: @AhmedNuaman remember that you can also use data-ng-click and x-ng-click attributes see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746916/can-i-use-another-prefix-instead-of-ng-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using "data-ng-click"? Angular will still work with data- appended before it's attribute names and this should be valid syntax in older browsers.

```
<a data-ng-click="loadSomeDatas()" href="#">Click here to load some datas</a>
```